# Generate an overall league table

Tags: mysql

I am making a small soccer prediction website and one functionality I need is to generate a league table from my database that contains past results. My db has 5 columns;

Fixture_ID.

Home_team.

Away_team.

Htgoals( Number of goals scored by home team).

Atgoals( Number of goals scored by away team).

I have two queries that return the league tables for teams only when playing at home and playing away from home

```
Home-" Select results.Home_team, 
SUM(if(results.Htgoals > results.Atgoals,3,0)) AS W,
SUM(IF(results.Htgoals = results.Atgoals,1,0)) AS D,
SUM(IF(results.Htgoals < results.Atgoals,1,0)) AS L
from results
GROUP BY results.Home_team
order by W desc";

Away table-" Select results.Away_team,
SUM(if(results.Atgoals > results.Htgoals,3,0)) AS W,
SUM(IF(results.Atgoals = results.Htgoals,1,0)) AS D,
SUM(IF(results.Atgoals < results.Htgoals,1,0)) AS L
FROM results
GROUP BY results.Away_team
ORDER BY W DESC";
```

How can I;

1.Do a union to generate an overall league table

2.Rank teams by the number of points rather than number of wins

Comment: So you enter 2 rows for each match? I think you need to reconsider the data model.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not that far away from the query I would use. I would combine the 2 queries without group by clause in a subquery and do the group by a summing wins, losses, draws, and points in the outer query:

```
select team, sum(W) as W, sum(D) as D, sum(L) as L, sum(W * 3 + D) as Points
FROM
((Select results.Home_team as team, 
if(results.Htgoals > results.Atgoals,1,0) AS W,
IF(results.Htgoals = results.Atgoals,1,0) AS D,
IF(results.Htgoals < results.Atgoals,1,0) AS L
from results)
UNION
(Select results.Away_team,
if(results.Atgoals > results.Htgoals,3,0) AS W,
IF(results.Atgoals = results.Htgoals,1,0) AS D,
IF(results.Atgoals < results.Htgoals,1,0) AS L
FROM results)) t
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY Points desc
```

When calculating the points I assumed 3 for wins and 1 for draws.